# Function that can be used for an array of any size

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that will work regardless of the size of the array, I am stuck and cannot figure it out. I understand that this current code doesn't work because I am entering 10 pieces of data into the memory of an array that only stores 5. Looking for a simple solution and a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void getInput(int []);

int main()
{
    int numbers[5], 
        nums[10],
        i;

    getInput(numbers);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
           cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    getInput(nums);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
           cout << nums[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

   _getch();
   return 0;
}

void getInput(int num[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that you're using C++, use a `std::vector`

Comment: So pass the #elements in as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the function how many numbers to work with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void getInput(int [], int);

int main()
{
    int numbers[5], 
        nums[10],
        i;

    getInput(numbers, 5);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    getInput(nums, 10);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}

void getInput(int num[], int maxnums)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxnums; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter number #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
}
```

If you only ever pass in static arrays (this won't work for dynamic arrays or pointers), you can automate passing the array size by making the function use a template argument and let the compiler deduce the value for each passed array:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <const size_t n>
void getInput(int (&nums)[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Enter number #" << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> num[i];
    }
}    

int main()
{
    int numbers[5], 
        nums[10],
        i;

    getInput(numbers);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    getInput(nums);

    cout << "\nThe numbers are:\t";
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```